# how to import component from another application

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My typescript+react app contains some public page like pay/login/footer, so I am trying to create a new react application  `npx create-react-app rd-component --template typescript` and put these public component. Then reuse these component in different project. First, I write a simple component like this in `src/componnet/demo` folder:

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

const CommonPage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  React.useEffect(() => {
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default CommonPage;
```

then export this component in src/index.tsx like this:

```
import CommonPage from "./component/demo/CommonPage";

export { CommonPage }
```

then I build this package to tgz package and install `npm install ~/source/reddwarf/frontend/rd-component/rd-component-0.1.0.tgz` into another project and tried to import the component:

```
import CommomPage from "rd-component";
```

shows error:

```
Cannot find module 'rd-component' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
No quick fixes available
```

am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? when specify the full path, works:

```
import CommomPage from "rd-component/src/component/demo/CommonPage";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you export this `Common` component like this:

```
import CommonPage from "./component/demo/CommonPage";

export { CommonPage }
```

> then I build this package to tgz package and install npm install ~/source/reddwarf/frontend/rd-component/rd-component-0.1.0.tgz into another project and tried to import the component:

You actually want to import this component `CommonPage` not `CommomPage`

```
import CommonPage from "rd-component";
```